# Single sign on - Sharepoint to Web app

Tags: sharepoint, windows-authentication, single-sign-on

We have a Sharepoint site that uses Windows based authentication.

We provide links in Sharepoint to a secure web app that uses forms based authentication. Both authenticate against the same AD.

However, the issue is when clicking a link in Sharepoint, they are prompted to re-authenticate when reaching the web app. This is a hassle as their username/password are obviously the same since authenticating against the same source.

Are there any examples or helpful docs on getting single sign-on to work from windows based authentication to forms based authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're navigating between subdomains on the same domain (like www.YOURDOMAIN.com to app.YOURDOMAIN.com) you can get the desired results with a **domain level asp.net authentication cookie** using [`SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) and some web.config changes.

This article was helpful when I setup a similar configuration [Single Sign-on in ASP.NET and Other Platforms - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx)

### Step 1 - Set Cookie

Even though the SharePoint app uses Windows auth, you can still call this method to create a .NET auth cookie for your current domain and auto authenticate the user when they navigate to your forms auth app.  So, once your user logs into your SharePoint site apply the cookie (possibly via a custom web part or page/masterpage code-behind) like so:

```
// this will create a persistant cookie 
// (meaning closing/re-opening the browser won't remove the cookie)
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(
    SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, 
    true);
```

### Step 2 - Set Identical `<machineKey>` values

In the web.config of both applications you'll need to set identical values for your   [`<machineKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (inside `<system.web>`). Such as:

```
<machineKey 
  validation="SHA1" 
  validationKey="[128 character random string]" 
  decryption="AES" 
  decryptionKey="[64 character random string]" />
```

### Step 3 - Set `<forms>` values

You'll also want to set values in the [`<forms>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) tag so that when the auth cookie is created it will use your settings for `domain`, `cookieless`

in your SharePoint web.config apply the following

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms domain="YOURDOMAIN.COM" 
             cookieless="UseCookies"
             enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

in your forms-auth app set these in your web.config along with whatever you have already (probably at least your `loginUrl` and `timeout` property values are set also)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms domain="YOURDOMAIN.COM" 
             cookieless="UseCookies"
             enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```